# How can php not execute neither 'then' nor 'else' clauses of 'if'?

Tags: php, if-statement, header

Following [this tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL) (which I adapted to PostgreSQL), I have a problem in `register.inc.php`:

```
if (empty($error_msg)) {
    // Create a random salt
    $random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()), true));
    // Create salted password 
    $pwd = hash('sha512', $pwd.$random_salt);
    // Insert the new user into the database 
    $q = "insert into usr (username,email,pwd,salt) values ($1,$2,$3,$4);";
    $res = pg_query_params($conn,$q,[$username,$email,$pwd,$random_salt]);
    if ($res === false) {
        header("Location: ../html/coisas/error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT");
    } else {
        header('Location: ./register_success.php?msg=1'.$random_salt);
    }
    header('Location: ./register_success.php?msg=2'.$random_salt);
}
```

The header sent is the 3rd one (?msg=2...). If I comment it out, there's no header sent. How can it be that it won't enter in the then clause, nor in the else clause? The data is not being stored in the database, but I'm getting a "sucess" response. How can I know for sure the value of `$res`?

Comment: try an `if/elseif/else` for your headers and add `exit;` after each header. check for errors

Comment: have you tried to var_dump **$error_msg** ?

Comment: try to do a var_dump on `$error_msg`

Comment: `$error_msg` is ok. Do var_dump($res)

Comment: Actually I changed the === for == and it solved the problem! How can it be? The manual [http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php] says that, if things go wrong in the sql, pg_query_params return FALSE. Is FALSE different from false? I was using if (!$res) before, with the same error. PHP is so illogical sometimes!

Comment: No, but might be a flaw in the manual. There are lots of functions in PHP that can return either FALSE or "a value that can be evaluated as FALSE". But not all of them are described as it should. Try to `var_dump($res)` and see if it returns a bool false. If it does, then I stand corrected on all I've said. Anyway it doesn't present answer to your problem, since it should evaluate to FALSE anyway, and fall to `else` clause. The language is almost never wrong... usually, it's the programmer. If you find a bug, report it to PHP team :)

Comment: As I said, == worked. But how could I do a var_dump before or after the headers? The ideal would be to print to Firefox console, but still haven't figured out how to do it.

Comment: Because a `header` redirects to another page, you cannot see and echo'd output on the form that runs the `header` or the one you are redirecting to unless you add a message to the `get params` or drop it into `$_SESSION` and pick it up from there in the redirected form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `header()` will only work if it is sent before any other output is sent to the browser. I would guess that you have already sent something to the browser, maybe a debugging message or something.

If this has happened you should see a self explanitory error message in the `php error log`

Also you should always do an `exit;` after any `header()` statement as the `header()` does not actually stop execution of the rest of the script.

i.e.

```
if ($res === false) {
    header("Location: ../html/coisas/error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT");
    exit;
} else {
    header('Location: ./register_success.php?msg=1'.$random_salt);
    exit;
}
header('Location: ./register_success.php?msg=2'.$random_salt);
exit;
```

Comment: I only included the 3rd header because it was going in neither of the first two (what sounds absurd to me!). Please read my last comment on the question.

Comment: Of course DUH. `===` compares type as well as value. `false` is boolean and `$res` is type=resource with a value of zero. Types do not match. I always wondered why I only use `==` in those tests, now I know

Comment: Did you add the `exit;` as suggested. Otherwise it will redirect to the second and then continue execution and that will then redirect to the third.

Comment: Ok, I think that was the case then. I can't repeat the error now because I already solved the database error (lack of permission for a sequence), and don't want to unsolve it again. Thank you!